# connecting to WSO2 Identity Server from nodejs services

Tags: node.js, wso2, wso2-identity-server

My back end services are in Nodejs and I am planning to use wso2 identity server for authorization. For that , I have to hit OAuth2 based url's[authorize,token] from my node back-end. I have tried some nodejs oauth2 server implementation.But is it the same for WSO2 Identity server?
How can i connect from my NodeJS back end services to WSO2 identity server for authorization? which will be the end points should I use?

Answer (score 1):

All the OAuth2 Endpoints In WSO2 Identity Server are exposed as REST endpoints complying to the OAuth2 Specification. Therefore you wouldn't have any problem using a standard OAuth2 client in nodejs to fulfill your requirements.

These are the endpoints you need to be concerned about if you want to use OAuth2,

Authorization Endpoint URL: https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize

Token Endpoint URL: https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token
Token Revocation Endpoint URL:  https://localhost:9443/oauth2/revoke
Token introspection Endpoint URL:   https://localhost:9443/oauth2/introspect

[Change the hostname and port suitably.]

Comment: Thanks a lot .
I am using a password grant flow.
I got the tocken using token end point url.
When someone hits my protected url with a token , how should i authorise the token with that url?Which end point should i use ?
Can you please explain that flow as well.

Comment: Please ask this as a separate question. And please approve the answer if you believe this is the correct answer.